# Radio Streaming

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, audio-streaming, internet-radio

I setup a radioplayer, but the big problem is that the radio stops streaming when the screen of the phone goes black. Does anyone know why all of this ?

Here's the code :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

private Button buttonPlay;

private Button buttonStopPlay;

private MediaPlayer player;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    initializeUIElements();

    initializeMediaPlayer();
}

private void initializeUIElements() {



    buttonPlay = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonPlay);
    buttonPlay.setOnClickListener(this);

    buttonStopPlay = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonStopPlay);
    buttonStopPlay.setEnabled(false);
    buttonStopPlay.setOnClickListener(this);

}

public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v == buttonPlay) {
        startPlaying();
    } else if (v == buttonStopPlay) {
        stopPlaying();
    }
}

private void startPlaying() {
    buttonStopPlay.setEnabled(true);
    buttonPlay.setEnabled(false);


    player.prepareAsync();

    player.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {

        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
            player.start();
        }
    });

}

private void stopPlaying() {
    if (player.isPlaying()) {
        player.stop();
        player.release();
        initializeMediaPlayer();
    }

    buttonPlay.setEnabled(true);
    buttonStopPlay.setEnabled(false);

}

private void initializeMediaPlayer() {
    player = new MediaPlayer();
    try {        
         player.setDataSource("http://69.46.75.99/");
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    player.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(new OnBufferingUpdateListener() {

        public void onBufferingUpdate(MediaPlayer mp, int percent) {

            Log.i("Buffering", "" + percent);
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (player.isPlaying()) {
        player.stop();
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You should consider using a `Service` or else you'll need to acquire a partial wakelock. Using a `Service` is trickier but is the better option.

See [Using a Service with MediaPlayer](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html#mpandservices)

Comment: Can you set it up for me ? I don't understand english very good, and in the tutorial are a lot of words that i don't understand.